# How to install Ipopt on Google Colab for Pyomo?

Tags: optimization, pyomo, ipopt, googlecolab

I need to use Pyomo with Ipopt solver on Google-Colab.

In order to install it I did as follows:
[image]

Now I need to use it , I get the following error ?
**ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'**

[image]

How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following package installation should be done before staring the Pyomo model

```
!pip install pyomo 
from pyomo.environ import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!wget -N -q "https://matematica.unipv.it/gualandi/solvers/ipopt-linux64.zip"
!unzip -o -q ipopt-linux64
```

Then you can run your **NLP** model

```
model = AbstractModel()
model.x = Var(bounds=(0,1.2), within=Reals)
model.obj1 = Objective(expr=model.x**2, sense=maximize)
#opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt=SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/content/ipopt')
instance = model.create_instance()
results = opt.solve(instance) # solves and updates instance
print('OF= ',value(instance.obj1))
```

Comment: thanks 
is it possible to show how to use the same approach for MINLP ? 
how can I give the address of solver ?
for example, instaed of using your ipopt address which one of these can be used ?
https://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Ipopt/

Answer (score 5):

If your notebook could be executed both on Colab or on a different environment (such as a local Jupyter notebook), you could add a couple of checks, before downloading and reinstalling `pyomo` and `ipopt` every time, as follows:

```
import shutil
import sys
import os.path

if not shutil.which("pyomo"):
    !pip install -q pyomo
    assert(shutil.which("pyomo"))

if not (shutil.which("ipopt") or os.path.isfile("ipopt")):
    if "google.colab" in sys.modules:
        !wget -N -q "https://matematica.unipv.it/gualandi/solvers/ipopt-linux64.zip"
        !unzip -o -q ipopt-linux64
    else:
        try:
            !conda install -c conda-forge ipopt 
        except:
            pass
```

**NOTE**: I have modified the link to ipopt-linux64.zip on Feb. 22nd, 2023. Older binaries of IpOpt are available at [COIN-OR](https://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Ipopt/)

Thanks to Stefano Coniglio and Pietro Belotti for the support on this.

**NOTE 2**: Since it was asked in a comment, you can install GLPK as follows:

```
if not (shutil.which("glpk") or os.path.isfile("glpk")):
    if "google.colab" in sys.modules:
        !apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils
    else:
        try:
            !conda install -c conda-forge glpk 
        except:
            pass
```

For other solvers, the process is quite similar (e.g., for CBC).

Comment: Hi Stefano, https://ampl.com/dl/open/ipopt/ipopt-linux64.zip no longer exists

Comment: This is a pity. We should look for an alternative website with that code. Thanks for letting us know about it.

Comment: @Optimizationteam I stored the ipopt file somewhere else (and I hope nobody complaints about it).

Comment: I understand, my question is when I give the address of ipopt or other coin-or solvers it does not work 

how can I use your approach for otehr solvers ? https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/

Comment: I tried all the methods in this answer, but mostly I'm getting the error : `[ipopt-linux64.zip] End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of ipopt-linux64 or ipopt-linux64.zip, and cannot find ipopt-linux64.ZIP, period.`

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that works for installing the solver on windows, i dont know if that will help, but here it is :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB_qVoM74Fg